# How to reconcile Angular's "always use dots with ngModel" rule with isolate scopes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope

I am working on an Angular app using Bootstrap.

In order to minimize the Bootstrap footprint on my HTML, I've introduced two directives for forms:

**form-control.js**

```
module.directive('formControl', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    templateUrl : 'form-control.tmpl.html',
    scope: {
      label: '@'
    },
    transclude : true
  };
});
```

**form-control.tmpl.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
    {{ label }}
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10"
       ng-transclude>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also have a handful of "extensions" to this directive, for various form input fields. e.g.:

**form-input-text.js**

```
module.directive('formInputText', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    templateUrl : 'form-input-text.tmpl.html',
    scope: {
      label: '@',
      value: '=ngModel'
    }
  };
});
```

**form-input-text.tmpl.html**

```
<form-control label="{{label}}">
  <input type="text"
         class="form-control"
         ng-model="value">
</form-control>
```

**app.html**

```
<form-input-text label="Name"
                 ng-model="person.name">
</form-input-text>
```

Here I run into a problem. There are a number of scopes in play in this example:

```
appScope = { person : { name : "John" } };
isolateScope = {
  label: "Name",
  value: "John" // bound two-way with appScope.person.name
};
transcludeScope = {
  __proto__: isolateScope,
  label: "Name", // inherited from isolateScope
  value: "John" // inherited from isolateScope
};
```

If I change the text in the input text box, then only `transcludeScope` is modified:

```
appScope = { person : { name : "John" } };
isolateScope = {
  label: "Name",
  value: "John" // bound two-way with appScope.person.name
};
transcludeScope = {
  __proto__: isolateScope,
  label: "Name", // inherited from isolateScope
  value: "Alice" // overrides value from isolateScope
};
```

This is because the `<input>` is bound directly to a property of `transcludeScope`. `transcludeScope.value` is changed directly, and the parent scope `isolateScope` is unaffected. Thus any model changes in the input never make it back to `appScope`.

What I'd like to do is create a two-way binding between `appScope.person.name` and a nested property of `isolateScope`, e.g. `isolateScope.model.value`.

Ideally I'd like to declare my directive like this:

**form-input-text.js**

```
module.directive('formInputText', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    templateUrl : 'form-input-text.tmpl.html',
    scope: {
      model: {
        label: '@',
        value: '=ngModel'
      }
    }
  };
});
```

This would allow the transcluded portion to bind to `model.value`, which would make changes visible to isolateScope, which would in turn propagate changes in `isolateScope` back to `appScope`.

This usage does not seem to be directly supported by Angular.

Can anyone point me to a feature of Angular that supports this use case, or if not, provide a workaround?

Edit:

For now, my solution is to inline the `form-control` template into the `form-input-text` template.

**form-input-text.tmpl.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
    {{ label }}
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           ng-model="value">
  </div>
</div>
```

This eliminates the child scope introduced `ng-transclude`, but it also duplicates markup, which is what I was hoping to refactor into a single place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking about scopes is actually going slightly on the wrong track, and I don't think the transclusion has much to do with it. To do it "properly", you should integrate with `ngModelController`. This allows any later integrated parsers and formatters (which could contain validation logic) to run at the appropriate times. It's a bit complicated as you have 2 of them: the parent one in the application, and the one in the template of the directive, and each one has 2 "pipelines" to be integrated with:

- model value -> view value
- view value -> model value

The view value of the parent ngModelController is then used as the model value of the inner ngModelController. So the overall pipelines look like

- parent model value -> parent view value -> inner model value -> inner view value
- inner view value -> inner model value -> parent view value -> parent model value

To do this:

- Make sure you `require: 'ngModel'` in the directive definition, to have access to the parent `ngModelController`
- Changes from the parent ngModelController to the inner, are done using the `$render` method of the parent `ngModelController`, using its `$viewValue`. This ensures that any functions in the parent `$formatters` have run.
- User initiated changes from the inner directive are done by adding a function to its `$viewChangeListeners` array, which calls `$setViewValue` on the parent `ngModelController`. To access this from the linking function scope, you need a named form and input elements. A slight annoyance is that the form is only registered on the scope of the directive after its linking function of the directive has run, so you need a watcher to access it.
- Just in case of any weirdnesses, make sure that the model in `formInputText` is in an object. (I'm not sure this is technically necessary)
- You then *don't* need to have the model in the `scope` object of the inner directive.

Putting this together,

```
app.directive('formInputText', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    templateUrl : 'form-input-text.tmpl.html',
    scope: {
      label: '@'
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
      scope.model = {};

      // Propagate changes from parent model to local
      ngModelController.$render = function() {
        scope.model.value = ngModelController.$viewValue;
      };

      // Propagate local user-initiated changes to parent model
      scope.$watch('form', function(form) {
        if (!form) return;
        form.input.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
          ngModelController.$setViewValue(form.input.$modelValue);
        });       
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And its template looks like

```
<form-control label="{{label}}" ng-form name="form">
  <input type="text"
         class="form-control"
         name="input"
         ng-model="model.value">
</form-control>
```

This can be seen working at http://plnkr.co/edit/vLGa6c55Ll4wV46a9HRi?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom control for your case, as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), making the custom `<form-input-*>` directives true controls. It does need some additional work. To outline a simplistic version of a solution:

**form-input-text.js**

```
app.directive('formInputText', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        template : '<form-control label="{{label}}"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></form-control>',
        scope: {
            label: '@'
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            var input = angular.element(elem[0].querySelectorAll("input")[0]);

            ngModel.$render = function() {
                input.val(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
            };

            input.on('blur keyup change', function() {
                scope.$apply(read);
            });

            function read() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(input.val());
            }
        }
    };
});
```

In short, you `require` the `ngModel` and implement its methods, as per the documentation. The `ngModel` is just another directive applied to your control and other things will work, e.g. custom validators, `ng-required` and so on.

A working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1n53q59z/

Bear in mind that you may need to do some tweaking depending on your use case.